# navigate to calling code Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to know that we can use F12 to jump to the function that is called from this code , if i have to return to the code again how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the command you're looking for is "Navigate Backward", available from the View menu (or CTRL+-). It has a companion command, once invoked, called "Navigate Forward", also on View menu (CTRL+SHIFT+-).

You can use these to move back and forth through a chain of Calling/Callee functions. Obviously, if you're not using the usual Visual Studio shortcut mappings, then the key combinations above may be different (or you may have to assign keys yourself).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply...Damien_The_Unbeliever